# Java GUI cant draw Image

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //panel
        MyPanel panel1= new MyPanel();
        //
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.pack();
        //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setTitle("astra");
        //visisble
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
package com.company;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static java.awt.Color.BLACK;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    Image enemy;

    MyPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));
        this.setBackground(BLACK);
        enemy= new ImageIcon("ENEMY_4.png").getImage();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(enemy,0,0,null);
        //g2.drawLine(0,0,250,250);
    }

}
```

This should draw an Image on top but it doesnt.
I have checked the name of the file and its not wrong.
The location is not the problem because i have done it again but with JLabels.
The code is basically copy paste from youtube.
Any ideas?
I have used both intellij and eclipse and my problem is the same.
It just paints black the panel but doesnt draw the image.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? A NullPointerException? Have you checked what `enemy= new ImageIcon("ENEMY_4.png").getImage();` this returns? Is it null? You probably should be getting your images as resources, not as files (as you are currently doing).

Comment: I have put the same image in JLabels and worked fine.

Comment: Its ok..it worked.The location of file was the problem.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I put the image outside the src and it worked.